# batch file loop not showing most recent directory

Tags: windows, sorting, batch-file, cmd, echo

I am trying to loop through one directory and pic out the sub directory, which may be buried within other directories, and pull out the directory that has been most recently created.  I have a loop here which will go into the root directory, which is set, and look at only directories, incorporate all sub directories, sort them by creation date, and have the loop set the one at the end of the list be the most recent which is then echoed out.  However, for some reason the sorting does not happen correctly. It keeps pulling out a directory that is not the most recent.  I cannot seem to pinpoint the issue. What could be causing this? Am I using the sorting correctly? Does it not compare sub directories to other directories on other levels? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET dir=C:\Users\Darren\Google Drive\
echo %dir%
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir "%dir%" /b /s /ad-h /t:c /od') DO (
echo %%i
SET a=%%i)
SET sub=%a%
echo Most recent subfolder: %sub%
```

Comment: `dir/od` sort in order of date for the current directory, so your code will select the last-created directoryname in the last directory encountered, not the last-created-of-all-directories-and-subdirectories. You would need to sort a list of directories with the date extracted to a yymmddhhmmss format if you want the last-created directoryname. Not particularly hard, but not a one-line either. Consider whether you want the create date or the last-update date - and why do you want that directory? Are you actually looking for the last-(created) file?

Comment: That's what I figured.  Couldn't I just build a list of all the directories and then sort them by date created? My ultimate goal is to find out the most recent directory created and send an email notification if there are more than 20 files in it.  I have all other aspects of the script working, just not the sorting.

Comment: If they are all in the same directory, yes. If they aren't, you need to compare dates by breaking down the date-string (need to know which format you use) into yymm... Another way could be to log the directory-tree into a file and see what new one appear - point being that if the new directories don't all share a parent, you'd still need to sort them by comparing dates. Wouldn't you want to be notified of all new directories containing >20 files? That should be easier to build.

Comment: How would I go about logging the entire directory tree into a file? The way I have it set up now is I have a program that monitors the parent directory for any folder or file creation and then triggers this bat file to run.  The script knows that a new directory has been created but doesn't know which one.  So, I need to find which one is the most recent and check to see if it contains 20 or more files.Would it be easier to do all of this in a bat file?

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q43579378.txt"
SET "filename2=%sourcedir%\q43579378_2.txt"
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /s /ad "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO ECHO %%~a
)>"%filename1%"

IF EXIST "%filename2%" (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('findstr /L /V /i /x /g:"%filename2%" "%filename1%"') DO (
  FOR /f %%c IN ('dir /b /a-d "%%a\*" 2^>nul^|find /c /v "" ') DO (
   IF %%c gtr 20 ECHO(send email directory %%a has %%c files
  )
 )
)

MOVE "%filename1%" "%filename2%" >nul
GOTO :EOF
```

I used a test directory as `sourcedir`. Naturally, it doesn't have to be the same as the directory you're scanning, and the filenames can be whatever you like.

The first `for` builds a list of the absolute dirctorynames currently existing into `filename1` (the "spare" pair of parentheses enclosing the `for` allows the redirection)

If `filename2` exists (which will be for every run after the first), then find the difference between `filename1` and `filename2`, using `/L` literal, `/v` doesn't match `/i` case-insensitive `/x` exact match `/g:` strings in this file and assign each new directoryname to `%%a`.

Then scan the directory of `"%%a"`, files only, suppressing `file not found` messages and counting the number of returned lines (`/c` count `/v` lines not matching `""` an empty string). Assign the re4sult to `%%c`, test and choose where to take action.

the carets `^` before the redirectors in the command-to-be-executed of the `for ... %%c` command escape the redirectors so that they are interpreted as part of the command-to-be-executed, not the `for`.

Comment: Why not stating `dir /b /s /ad "%sourcedir%\*" > "%filename1%"` instead of using a `for /F` loop for this?

Answer (score 0):

The `dir /S /O` command sorts the content of every sub-directory individually, and there is no way to change that behaviour.

---

A possible alternative approach is to use the `wmic` command, which is a bit slow but capable of deriving the date information (creation, last modification, last access) in a standardised, sortable, region- and locale-independent format:

```cmd
wmic FSDir where Name="D:\\Data" get CreationDate /VALUE
wmic FSDir where (Name="D:\\Data") get CreationDate /VALUE
```

So below are two scripts that use a `for /D /R` loop to get all the (sub-)directories, the above `wmic` command lines, `for /F` to capture their output and a simple command to do the sorting by age.

---

The first one creates a temporary file to collect all directories, together with their creation dates, in the following format:

> ```cmd
> 20170424215505.000000+060 D:\Data
> ```

For sorting, the `sort` command is used. Here is the code:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=%~1"  & rem // (use first command line argument as the root directory)
set "_PATTERN=*" & rem // (search pattern for directories; `*` matches all)
set "_TMPF=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp" & rem // (specify a temporary file)

rem // Write list of directory paths preceded by their creation dates to temporary file:
> "%_TMPF%" (
    set "ERR=0"
    rem // Enumerate all matching directories recursively:
    for /D /R "%_ROOT%" %%D in ("%_PATTERN%") do (
        rem // Store currently iterated directory path:
        set "DIRPATH=%%~D"
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid trouble with the exclamation mark:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        (
            rem /* Capture `wmic` output to query creation date of currently iterated
            rem    directory in locale-dependent and sortable format: */
            for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%L in ('
                rem/ Do two attempts, because one approach can handle `^)` and one can handle `,`; ^& ^
                    rem/ note that `wmic` cannot handle paths containing both of these characters: ^& ^
                    2^> nul wmic FSDir where Name^="!DIRPATH:\=\\!" get CreationDate /VALUE ^|^| ^
                    2^> nul wmic FSDir where ^(Name^="!DIRPATH:\=\\!"^) get CreationDate /VALUE
            ') do (
                rem // Do nested loop to avoid Unicode conversion artefacts (`wmic` output):
                for /F %%K in ("%%L") do echo(%%K !DIRPATH!
            )
        ) || (
            rem // This is only executed in case a path contains both `)` and `,`:
            >&2 echo ERROR: Could not handle directory "!DIRPATH!"^^!
            set "ERR=1"
        )
        endlocal
    )
)
rem /* Return content of temporary file in sorted manner using `sort` command,
rem    remember last item of sorted list; clean up temporary file: */
for /F "tokens=1*" %%C in ('sort "%_TMPF%" ^& del "%_TMPF%"') do set "LASTDIR=%%D"
rem // Return newest directory:
echo "%LASTDIR%"

endlocal
exit /B %ERR%
```

---

The second one stores each directory in a variable named of the creation date, in the following format:

> ```cmd
> $20170424215505.000000+060=D:\Data
> ```

For sorting, the `set` command is used. Here is the code:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=%~1"  & rem // (use first command line argument as the root directory)
set "_PATTERN=*" & rem // (search pattern for directories; `*` matches all)

set "ERR=0"
rem // Clean up variables beginning with `$`:
for /F "delims==" %%C in ('2^> nul set "$"') do set "%%C="
rem // Enumerate all matching directories recursively:
for /D /R "%_ROOT%" %%D in ("%_PATTERN%") do (
    rem // Store currently iterated directory path:
    set "DIRPATH=%%~D"
    rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid trouble with the exclamation mark:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    (
        rem /* Capture `wmic` output to query creation date of currently iterated
        rem    directory in locale-dependent and sortable format: */
        for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%L in ('
            rem/ Do two attempts, because one approach can handle `^)` and one can handle `,`; ^& ^
                rem/ note that `wmic` cannot handle paths containing both of these characters: ^& ^
                2^> nul wmic FSDir where Name^="!DIRPATH:\=\\!" get CreationDate /VALUE ^|^| ^
                2^> nul wmic FSDir where ^(Name^="!DIRPATH:\=\\!"^) get CreationDate /VALUE
        ') do (
            rem // Do nested loop to avoid Unicode conversion artefacts (`wmic` output):
            for /F %%K in ("%%L") do (
                rem /* Assign currently iterated path to variable named of the
                rem    respective creation date preceded by `$`: */
                endlocal & set "$%%K=%%~D"
            )
        )
    ) || (
        endlocal
        rem // This is only executed in case a path contains both `)` and `,`:
        >&2 echo ERROR: Could not handle directory "%%~D"!
        set "ERR=1"
    )
)
rem /* Return all variables beginning with `$` in sorted manner using `set` command,
rem    remember last item of sorted list: */
for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%C in ('2^> nul set "$"') do set "LASTDIR=%%D"
rem // Return newest directory:
echo "%LASTDIR%"

endlocal
exit /B %ERR%
```